# Does TeamCity shares tests changes from different branches?

Tags: testing, teamcity

We are developing a project using Git, Gerrit and TeamCity.
we had a test that was failing, and TeamCity reported it correctly.
Then we had 2 commits submitted at the same time, one of them fixed the test. 
The tests started running for both commits. The first commit passed with all of the tests. The second commit, due to not pulling the changes yet, passed all of the tests except for the broken one. Nevertheless, Teamcity didn't report on it and just hid this test. It even updated Gerrit as if the tests passed.
The test was not muted in teamcity, and when I checked the run area of the tests I could see the test ran and failed- just wasn't reported.

Is this a bug or just a strange feature?
I can understand the logic behind such behavior, but not without reporting on the failing test.

Comment: I believe the order is important here.

 1. First, the order of the commits. "At the same time" won't do: one of them was committed first, or at least TC will consider one of them as committed before the other. Try and find out from the change history for the build config.
 2. Second, the order in which the builds started. If they were running in parallel, each on a different agent, then it's quite possible TC ran them out of order.
 3. Third, the order in which the builds finished.

This should give us some hints about what was going on.

Comment: Well yeah of course there is no actual "same time"- I just wanted to clarify that one of the commits had a fix for the test and the second one didn't, since they both were submitted for testing.
The commit with the fix ran first, but failed due to some environment problem. So we re-ran it. As a result, the commit without the fix was the prior build (from the builds that eventually passed). They ran on different agents.  The commit with the fix finish second.

Comment: When you say "The commit with the fix finish second.": did TC mark it as a historical build, since the commit with the fix was made before the other commit?

Comment: I'm not sure what is a 'historical build', but tc shows that this build is the second patch of that branch- which is the prior branch

Comment: Re "historical build": when you look at the build configuration overview tab, a historical build is in italics and has the word "History" in the "Changes" column. Which means that by the time it ran, it wasn't the latest commit anymore. You can also cause this by clicking the "Run ..." button and choosing an older commit on the "Changes" tab of the Run dialog.

Comment: I don't have any 'history', in any of the builds. But it might be due to us using automatic continuous integration ?

Comment: Sorry, it's very hard to get to the bottom of what happened without seeing it firsthand. But my past experience says that there's always a more-or-less satisfactory explanation, which confirms that TeamCity did the right thing. Unless this bothers you systematically, I wouldn't worry about this one case too much.

Comment: OK then, I will keep monitoring it and see how it's behaving. Thank you very much for your help!